# PIL Image.getcolors() cannot distinguish between black and transparent?

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library, transparent

I'm trying to count the number of distinct colors in an image using `img.getcolors()`. However, this does not distinguish between transparent and black pixels - they both report as one pixel colored [0,0,0].

How can I distinguish between transparent and black pixels? Many of the images I need to process are largely black on a transparent background.

For test purposes, I'm using a PNG I created which is half transparent, half black. `len(img.getcolors())` is 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get alpha value of a PNG image with PIL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962795/how-to-get-alpha-value-of-a-png-image-with-pil)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I read that other answer before I asked my question and it didn't help clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing answer:

I was using `convert('RGB')` before calling `getcolors()`. Without the conversion, a 4-value tuple comes back with an alpha channel.