# Changed behaviour of ImageEnhance.Brightness in Pillow

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, brightness

I'm trying to paste image B over image A with half opacity (i.e. pasted image is half transparent).

In version 2.1.0 of pillow the following code worked, in version 3.3.1 it no longer works:

```
A = Image.open('A.png')

B = Image.open('B.png')
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(B)
mask = enhancer.enhance(0.5)
print(mask.getpixel((10,10)), mask.getpixel((30,30)))
mask.save('Mask.png')

A.paste(B, (0,0), mask)
A.save('Result.png')
```

Image A is a black 'A' on a white background

Image B is a red 'B' on a transparent background

Images are provided below

Version 2.1.0 produces (127,0,0,127) for pixel 30,30 of the mask

Version 3.3.1 produces (127,0,0,255) for pixel 30,30 of the mask

[Image A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9yVz.png)
[Image B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1BZE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pillow is correct, changing the brightness of a pixel *should not* change its transparency. Obviously there was a bug in PIL.

What you really want is to split the alpha from image B and turn *that* into a mask. Using the technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1963146/5987):

```
mask = B.split()[-1]
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(mask)
mask = enhancer.enhance(0.5)
```