# Converting png to pdf with PIL save mode error

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Im trying to convert png files into pdf's. `PIL` seems to be the way to do it but Im getting an error (`cannot save mode RGBA`) when running it

Code:

```
import os
import PIL
from PIL import Image

path = 'E:\path_to_file'
filename = '15868799_1.png'
fullpath_filename = os.path.join(path, filename)
im = PIL.Image.open(fullpath_filename)
newfilename = '15868799.pdf'
newfilename_fullpath = os.path.join(path, newfilename)
PIL.Image.Image.save(im, newfilename_fullpath, "PDF", resoultion=100.0)
```

Error:

```
 File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py", line 148, in _save
 raise ValueError("cannot save mode %s" % im.mode)
 ValueError: cannot save mode RGBA
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to [convert your PNG from RGBA to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166400/convert-rgba-png-to-rgb-with-pil) first.

Sample code:

```
from PIL import Image

PNG_FILE = 'E:\path_to_file\15868799_1.png'
PDF_FILE = 'E:\path_to_file\15868799.pdf'

rgba = Image.open(PNG_FILE)
rgb = Image.new('RGB', rgba.size, (255, 255, 255))  # white background
rgb.paste(rgba, mask=rgba.split()[3])               # paste using alpha channel as mask
rgb.save(PDF_FILE, 'PDF', resoultion=100.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert multiple `RGBA` png images, I opted for this code piece,

```py
from PIL import Image

_source = "/mnt/ssd/presentations"

_files = [] # List of image path populated using glob

def conv_rgba_to_rgb(_rgba):
  _rgba = Image.open(_rgba)
  _rgb = Image.new('RGB', _rgba.size, (255, 255, 255))
  _alpha = _rgba.split()[-1]
  _rgb.paste(_rgba, mask=_rgba.putalpha(_alpha))
  return _rgb

_images = [conv_rgba_to_rgb(_f) for _f in _files]
_pdf_path = f"{_source}/phd-presentation.pdf"
_images[0].save(_pdf_path, "PDF", resolution=72.0, save_all=True, append_images=_images[1:])
```

Comment: Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962795/how-to-get-alpha-value-of-a-png-image-with-pil), consider the following edits: Replace `_rgb.paste(_rgba, mask=_rgba.split()[3])` with `_alpha = _rgba.split()[-1]` followed by `_rgb.paste(_rgba, mask=_rgba.putalpha(_alpha))`

Comment: Updated! Thanks for improving the code piece @TedM.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a number of approaches for multiple picture file types. The code with fewest issues ended up appending `.convert('RGB')` to `PIL.Image.open()`. Here is a modification to the code from the original post.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFile
from PIL import UnidentifiedImageError
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
from pillow_heif import register_heif_opener

register_heif_opener()

path = 'E:\path_to_file'
filename = '15868799_1.png'
fullpath_filename = os.path.join(path, filename)
im = PIL.Image.open(fullpath_filename).convert('RGB')
newfilename = '15868799.pdf'
newfilename_fullpath = os.path.join(path, newfilename)
PIL.Image.Image.save(im, newfilename_fullpath, "PDF", resolution=100.0)
```