# Converting and merging Images and PDF with Python

Tags: python, pdf, automation

So, i'm trying to combine multiple files (PDF's and images) using just Python. So far managed to do with PDFs and "JPG" images. However, everytime i try to convert "PNG" images to PDF using PIL, an error pops-up saying "ValueError: cannot save mode RGBA".

I know PIL can convert "RGBA" to "RGB" but for some reason the code below is not working properly.

Any ideas why?

***P.S.:*** Started learning Python one week ago, if it's obvious to you, please, be kind.

***PYTHON CODE***

```
# pip instal PyPDF2

from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys
import img2pdf
from PIL import Image 
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

source_dir = sys.argv[1]

os.chdir(sys.argv[1])

print(sys.argv[1])

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    
    if item.endswith('jpg'):
        print(item)
        output = "output.pdf"
        print(output)

        if os.path.isfile(output):
            expand = 1
            while True:
                expand += 1
                new_output = output.split(".pdf")[0] + str(expand) + ".pdf"
                print(new_output)
                
                if os.path.isfile(new_output):
                    continue
                else:
                    output = new_output
                    Image.open(item).save(output, "PDF", resolution=100.0)
                    break
                    
                    
        if not os.path.isfile(output):
                    print(output)
                    Image.open(item).save(output, "PDF", resolution=100.0)

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
        
    if item.endswith('png'):
        print(item)
        saida = "saida.pdf"
        print(saida)
        if Image.open(item).mode == "RGBA":
            Image.open(item).convert("RGB")

        if os.path.isfile(saida):
            expande = 1
            while True:
                expand += 1
                new_saida = saida.split(".pdf")[0] + str(expande) + ".pdf"
                print(new_saida)
                
                if os.path.isfile(new_saida):
                    continue
                else:
                    saida = new_saida
                    Image.open(item).save(saida, "PDF", resolution=100.0)
                    break
                    
                    
        if not os.path.isfile(saida):
                    print(saida)
                    Image.open(item).save(saida, "PDF", resolution=100.0)
    
                       
for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    
    if item.startswith('Doc.'):
        merger.merge(position=0, fileobj=item, bookmark=None, pages=None)
        
    if item.endswith('pdf'):
        merger.append(item)
                  
merger.write('tentativa.pdf')
merger.close()


filepath = source_dir + "\\"

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if item.startswith('Doc'):
        docname = item
        os.rename(filepath + docname, filepath + 'delete.pdf')

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    
    if item.startswith('output'):
        os.remove(item)

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if item.startswith('delete'):
        os.remove(item)

    if item.startswith('tentativa'):
        docname2 = item
        os.rename(filepath + docname2, filepath + docname)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your PNG from RGBA to RGB first.
Png has an extra alpha channel hence RGBA.
RGBA is 32bit while RGB is 24bit.
as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50763236/converting-png-to-pdf-with-pil-save-mode-error)

Sample code:

```
from PIL import Image

PNG_FILE = 'a.png'
PDF_FILE = 'b.pdf'

rgba = Image.open(PNG_FILE)
rgb = Image.new('RGB', rgba.size, (255, 255, 255))  # white background
rgb.paste(rgba, mask=rgba.split()[3])               # paste using alpha channel as mask
rgb.save(PDF_FILE, 'PDF', resoultion=100.0)
```

Comment: So "Image.open(item).convert" do not work on this case?

Comment: ofcourse, you can open the image with the image.open() subclass but the type of data read and type of data expected will mismach while converting RGBA ==> RGB which is the line mentioning  [Image.open(item).convert("RGB") ] somewhere in your second for loop... JUST remove the mode and use the above code rgb= Image.new('RGB', rgba.size, (255, 255, 255)) and paste the data in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [convert your PNG from RGBA to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166400/convert-rgba-png-to-rgb-with-pil) first, like this:

```
from PIL import Image

PNG_FILE = 'image.png'
PDF_FILE = 'doc.pdf'

rgba = Image.open(PNG_FILE)
rgb = Image.new('RGB', rgba.size, (255, 255, 255))  # white background
rgb.paste(rgba, mask=rgba.split()[3])               # paste using alpha channel as mask
rgb.save(PDF_FILE, 'PDF', resoultion=100.0)
```